# np.random.choice doesn't do sampling as designated probabilities.

Tags: python, numpy, sampling

I'm trying to resample my sample data to calculate bootstrap standard error. But the results don't match the designated probabilities I made.

for 'p' in numpy.random.choice(a, size=None, replace=True, p=None), I assinged a **list of probabilities** which is

[0.190872103, 0.120820803, 0.115160092, 0.008137272, 0.029541836, 0.0,
0.535467893, 0.0] for  ['neutral', 'happy', 'sad', 'surprise', 'fear', 'disgust', 'anger','contempt'] each.

```
data = pd.read_csv(path+'shawshank_FER_entropy.csv', encoding = 'utf-8', delimiter='\t')

emo_list = ['neutral', 'happy', 'sad', 'surprise', 'fear', 'disgust', 'anger','contempt']

pb = data.andy
p = [float(pb.iloc[11]),float(pb.iloc[12]),float(pb.iloc[13]),float(pb.iloc[14]),float(pb.iloc[15]),float(pb.iloc[16]),float(pb.iloc[17]),float(pb.iloc[18])]

print(p)
emo_sample = np.random.choice(emo_list, 1000, p)

print(emo_sample)

unique, counts = np.unique(emo_sample, return_counts=True)
print(np.asarray((unique, counts)).T)
```

I expected results to be 1000 emotion words distributed as the probability I designated, but the results are uniformly distributed as below.

> [['anger' '128']  ['contempt' '140']  ['disgust' '101']  ['fear'
>   '134']  ['happy' '121']  ['neutral' '120']  ['sad' '123']  ['surprise'
>   '133']]

Can you explain why my codes don't use the probability I specified?

Comment: According to https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.15.0/reference/generated/numpy.random.choice.html you specified `replace`, not probabilities.

Comment: @dyukha replace is optional boolean parameter so I skipped it. it is 'p' that I specified.

Comment: You misunderstand optional parameters. unutbu’s answer explains it in detail.

Comment: @dyukha yes you were right. I mistakenly used 'p' only for 4th parameter.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[The call signature](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.15.0/reference/generated/numpy.random.choice.html) of numpy.random.choice is:

```
numpy.random.choice(a, size=None, replace=True, p=None)
```

Notice that `p` is the 4th parameter, not the 3rd.
So `emo_sample = np.random.choice(emo_list, 1000, p)` is assigning `p` to the `replace` parameter instead of the `p` parameter:

```
numpy.random.choice(a, size=None, replace=p, p=None)
```

One way to fix this is to use keyword parameters:

```
emo_sample = np.random.choice(emo_list, 1000, p=p)
```

Comment: Thanks, it worked. I thought I could just skip the 3rd parameter and use 'p' solely as probability parameter.